# ffmpeg - when merging an image and audio, audio gets shortened

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to merge a png image with 11 seconds of audio and create an mp4 file. When I execute ffmpeg I end up with a total duration of 10 seconds for the mp4 file. The command I'm using is...

```
ffmpeg -r 6 -loop 1 -i "image1.png" -i "audio1.wav" out.mp4
```

UPDATE: Here is the log that is produced...

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r15986, Copyright (c) 2000-2008 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-cflags=-fno-common --enable-memalign-hack --enable-pthr
  eads --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora
  --enable-libspeex --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-libx264 --enable-lib
schroedinger --enable-avisynth --enable-swscale --enable-gpl
      libavutil     49.12. 0 / 49.12. 0
      libavcodec    52. 6. 0 / 52. 6. 0
      libavformat   52.23. 1 / 52.23. 1
      libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
      libswscale     0. 6. 1 /  0. 6. 1
      built on Dec  3 2008 01:59:37, gcc: 4.2.4
Input #0, image2, from 'image1.png':
Duration: 00:00:00.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0.0: Video: png, rgb32, 400x300,  6.00 tb(r)
Input #1, wav, from 'audio1.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:11.07, bitrate: 88 kb/s
    Stream #1.0: Audio: pcm_u8, 11025 Hz, mono, s16, 88 kb/s
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 400x300, q=2-31, 200 kb/s,  6.00 tb(c)
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libfaac, 11025 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #1.0 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame=    1 fps=  0 q=4.1 Lsize=      42kB time=0.17 bitrate=2063.7kbits/s
video:14kB audio:26kB global headers:0.kB muxing overhead 4.894235%
```

I have also tried using

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "image1.png" -i "audio1.wav" -t 11 out.mp4
```

This command does create an mp4 of 11 seconds but the audio is still cut off at 10 seconds.

Why is the audio being cutoff at 10 seconds?

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: `SVN-r15986` is absolutely ancient and is unsupported. As of now there have been 49902 updates to FFmpeg since your version. Refer to the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

One possible thing is that your audio file is just 10 seconds long.
Are you sure you are losing a whole second of the audio? Maybe it is just a few miliseconds which could cause some rounding issues? You can check this by running

```
ffprobe "audio1.wav"
```

and then

```
ffprobe "out.mp4"
```

Adding some options of codec/bitrate (e.g. -c:a copy -b:a copy) might help

Comment: The length from ffprobe for the out.mp4 is 10.78 seconds and for audio1.wav it is 11.07. So it's about a .5 seconds shorter.